# How to stop Flask from serving several routes at the same time?

Tags: python, flask

I have some routes that should call an API if some term is not present in my database, then insert it in the database, otherwise, if it exists, it uses the record from the database, this logic is shared among 3 routes, the only difference is how the record is processed and each route returns a different response .

The problem is that I'm calling all these 3 routes async through AJAX, and when the term doesn't exist all the routes get it from the API and insert it, thus resulting in an unwanted behaviour of setting the same term 3 times in my database :

Here's how one of my route logic look like :

```
@search_bp.route("/search")
@login_required
def search():
    q = request.args["q"]

    data = tweets_coll.find({"query": q.lower()}) # querying record
    if tweets.count() == 0:
        # Means that record does not exist

        get_record_from_api()
        insert_in_db()


    record = get_from_db()

    return response
```

Here's a second route example:

```
@search_bp.route("/users")
@login_required
def get_users():
    q = request.args["q"]

    data = tweets_coll.find({"query": q.lower()}) # querying record
    if tweets.count() == 0:
        # Means that record does not exist

        get_record_from_api()
        insert_in_db()


    record = get_from_db()
    # Do some other processing here

    return response
```

I have the same condition in the 2 other routes (only record processing is different) . In my understanding, one of these 3 routes will get called first, check if record exist or not, if it doesn't it insert it in the DB, the other routes will execute, and it'll be guaranteed that the same record won't be inserted again, since it got inserted in the first route, and I'm doing the same checking logic

But apparently, flask serve multiple routes at the same time, I don't know how to make it serve one route at a  time ? or is there some way to run that checking and inserting before running the views ? I tried `before_request` but with no luck unfortunately .

Comment: Some dbs support an atomic read and write operation, such that you can check if something is the case and flip a bit in the db to create a writelock. Maybe you could try something like that with your db? Alternatively, maybe have all incoming requests get processed by a single celery worker?

Comment: Can you post the code to your other 2 routes?. Where are those routes receiving the requests from? is it a browser that is making the requests?

Comment: A simpler solution. Why not just store a set `processing_records` in your Flask app that's initially empty. When you get an AJAX request, you add the element that your'e processing to the `processing_records` set. Then if another AJAX request for the same element comes in, it can see that the given element is being processed currently. Once you're done working with an element, remove it from the set. Also, all routes that interact with this table should call a single function that will be the diplomat who interacts with the db. That diplomat can be in chart of updating your state variable.

Comment: @duhaime I'm using NoSQL with MongoDB, I don't know if this is possible and my database skills are not very advanced so I do not see what you actually mean, I'm looking for a solution Flask-side if it's possible

Comment: @shifloni I added a second route example logic, it's the same as the first, the difference only lies in how the record is processed, all the routes are in the same blueprint file `search_bp` , and I'm making the requests through a browser (usingg React in my frontend)

Comment: @Souames see my second comment above -- that's a pure flask solution. The short version: make one function that will interact with your database (factor this function out of the code you posted above). Make all 3 routes that need to interact with the db use that function. When that function is called, check to see if the record the function needs to check is currently being checked. If not, store in Flask an identifier for the record the function is going to work on. Then once the function completes, remove that record from the list of records being processed.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to make flask serve "one route at a time". one solution is to make an additional route that handles the insertion instead of handling it 3 times on each route. Your views can return True or False to the browser and then, after you ran all 3 cases depending on the response, you can make an additional ajax call to the view that handles the insertion.